# Python Return Sublist of Value's First Appearance and Onwards

Tags: python, list

I would please like your help to a university task I have. The task is this:

"Create a function in Python that requests a DNA or RNA sequence and a nucleotide as inputs from the user. After checking that the sequence and nucleotide are valid (check that it includes only the letters A,C,G,T,U), it must then return a sublist of the sequence from the first appearance of the nucleotide to the end of the list, or the empty list."

The code I wrote is the following:

```
def Sequence(seq,base):
    errors = 0
    # Check if the sequence is valid 
    for i in seq:
        if i in "ACGTU":
            if base in "ACGTU":
                continue
            else:
                errors +=1
        else:
            errors +=1
    # If the sequence is invalid
    if errors >0 or errors<0:
        print("The sequence/base is invalid.")
    # If the sequence is valid
    else:
        # Find the first appearance of the base and return list from this point to the end of the list
        list = 0
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            if seq[i]==base:
                list=i
                print(seq[list:])

# Input sequence from user
seq1 = input("Please enter sequence: ")
base1 = input("Please enter nucleotide: ")

# Convert input to upper case letters
seq1 = seq1.upper()
base1 = base1.upper()

Sequence(seq1,base1)
```

My issue is that this code doesn't only return the sublist of the first nucleotide appearance and onwards, but also the second appearance and onwards, and the third and onwards etc, which is not the requested task.

Can you please help?

Comment: Please fix the `indent` of the code first.    And try not use `built-in` `list` as the variable name...

Comment: Can you give a sample input/response?

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was harder, because you didn't explain very well in words, but your code comments were good and I got the logic from there.

here is my result code, I organized a little and made easier to understand.

```
def Sequence(seq, base):
    letters = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'U']
    # Check if the sequence is valid
    for i in seq:
        if i not in letters: return "The sequence/base is invalid."

    for i in base:
        if i not in letters: return "The sequence/base is invalid."

    # Find the first appearance of the base and return list from this point to the end of the list
    find = seq.find(base)
    if find != -1: return seq[find:]
    return "not found base inside sequence"


# Input sequence from user
seq = input("Please enter sequence: ").upper()
base = input("Please enter nucleotide: ").upper()

# Convert input to upper case letters
print(Sequence(seq, base))
```

Comment: Quick work! Wouldn't it be better to also put the upper() directly in Sequence function since the function always wants to work with upper case?

Comment: Good point, I added your recommendation.

Comment: @CesarLopes WOW you are amazing, this works perfectly!! i need to read it carefully so i understand it though its a little advanced for my level :D

Comment: I meant: always change seq and base to upper case **inside** the Sequence function.

Comment: @H3coder, I wouldn't do this, because it would only add more lines of code :/, If he used the lower case values of seq and base in other context, then that would be a good approach.

Comment: @kostasmath23, I'll try to introduce to you. instead of use if elses, it's better to check the else condition first and return the result, getting rid of the multiple if elses in the code. Instead of print inside the function, just return the text value saving lines of code and print the function result instead. lastly a string is an array too, of characters, and with str.find() you can get the index of the substring you are looking for, and as it is an array, you can print from the index of the found substring until the end with the code [index:] or you could use [index: len(string)]